# C# OpenTK - Linux Console without X11

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, console-application, opentk

I was just wondering if it is possible to render the OpenTK gamewindow in a Linux Console (Raspberry Pi Raspbian) without any X11 Desktop?

If it possible, how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's experimental since 1.1 or 1.2. Adjust `OpenTK.dll.config` if some dll could not be found, and maybe you'll have to find correct libinput version (`libinput-0.2.0` is working on my debian) to match api binding in opentk. I'm not fully sure, but I think that it's only working with modern GL (>3.0). 
Ensure you have `libdrm`, `libgbm` and correct `libinput` on your system and latest `mesa`.

OpenTK will automaticaly detect linux console environment if program is launched from a console.
If you face trouble finding missing dll's, enable full debug messages in Otk.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working but it took a bit of work. First I created a c library  to call through to the native libraries for controlling the gl chipset on the PI and exposed these so that I could call them from C#.

Secondly I had to recompile the opentk with the switch to not use dynamic bindings. In the end I stripped out most of the game window logic and just used the bindings and the maths code from opentk.

More details and code here:

http://www.opentk.com/node/4024

Basically this is enough to get you clearing / swapping the screen etc and you can then add the binding code through to the GL ES 2.0 spec which you can generate in the opentk project / solution tools.

Comment: Link is broken.