# Mono native compiler for Raspberry PI 3?

Tags: c#, mono, arm, raspberry-pi3

I've used monodevelop to create some iOS applications earlier. Worked great and the native samarin codegen produced solid binaries.

Well, i would like to do the same for Raspberry PI 3, but without X installed on the system. Basically use SDL to open screens, do owner-drawn widgets and last but not least - link to .lib/.obj files produced in vanilla C (in this case an emulator).

Is mono/C# still crippled to bytecodes or have they finally gotten rid of that? Bytecodes are great for moving code across platforms - but I would like to produce a single executable with no runtime dependencies as the final build. Preferably with some serious optimization involved (LLVM?)

Any way to do this? Would be fantastic if i could use C#

Comment: No, no way, the closest you can get is with .net Core native and I don't belive it exists for ARM linux. If you can live with the dependency to Mono then you can use OpenTK to achieve what you want with OpenGL (and there are some nice interface frameworks) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270432/c-sharp-opentk-linux-console-without-x11

Comment: Mono could pack a single binary from pretty much the beginning - see `mkbundle`.

Comment: Googled that, and it looks like there are some issues:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=18208

Comment: Last time I tried it worked ok for me - raspbian, hard float, relatively recent mono from git.

Comment: Didnt work here. I decided to go with Freepascal instead. Project almost done now. I'll leave the question until a definitive answer is defined. Miguel de icaza used to be on these questions in 2 seconds, perhaps he'll pick up the ball and make a PI codegen that doesnt depend on windows core (although considering MS now owns them i kinda doubt that).